# What are the main differences between 'use strict' and 'use strong' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, v8

Recently I came across a mode declaration `'use strong';` instead of the usual `'use strict';` in a JavaScript program.

What are the main differences between using `strict mode` and `strong mode` in JavaScript? Are there any advantages of one over another?

Reference: [Experiments with Strengthening JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/v8/experiments) on V8

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qk0qC4s_XNCLemj42FqfsRLp49nDQMZ1y7fwf5YjaI4/view

Comment: From what I know - `'use strong'` doesn't let you use `var`.
'use strict' - allows to use `var` but you have to assign it to something

Comment: literally 3 words search in google "use strong javascript"
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qk0qC4s_XNCLemj42FqfsRLp49nDQMZ1y7fwf5YjaI4/view

Comment: Which JS engines / browsers support strong mode?

Comment: I suppose it is supported only inside Chrome V8/Node environment but then the "only" here is quite big.

Comment: Does "strong" here means with respect to data-types and /or their behavior?